# Multivariate Breusch Godfrey Lagrange Multiplier tests in Python

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, statsmodels, multivariate-testing

I understand that in the package statsmodel has many statistical functions that enable one to test for many issues including Breusch Godfrey Lagrange test as described [here](http://www.statsmodels.org/dev/generated/statsmodels.stats.diagnostic.acorr_breusch_godfrey.html)

However, as far as I am concerned this only do the job for univariate case and not the multivariate case.

For example, consider I have a 2 diminsional dataset say data

```
from statsmodels.tsa.api import VAR
import statsmodels.api as sm,statsmodels as sm1

data= np.random.random((108, 2))
Model=VAR(data)
results = Model.fit(1)
sm.stats.diagnostic.acorr_breusch_godfrey(results)

Output: 
in acorr_breusch_godfrey(results, nlags, store)
    501         nlags = int(nlags)
    502 
--> 503     x = np.concatenate((np.zeros(nlags), x))
    504 
    505     #xdiff = np.diff(x)

ValueError: all the input arrays must have same number of dimensions
```

Hence, obviously, this only work for one dimensional, is anyone aware how to test for Breusch Godfrey in the multivariate setting?

Comment: Hi were you able to figure this out?

Comment: @dingo No, I think I have run it on R instead of Python! Python packages in stats are not as good as those in R.