# Statsmodels (Python): Breusch Godfrey Lagrange Multiplier tests

Tags: python, statsmodels

I am working with an autoregressive model in Python using Statsmodels. The package is great and I am getting the exact results I need. However, testing for residual correlation (Breusch-Godfrey LM-test) doesn't seem to work, because I get an error message.

My code:

```
import pandas as pd
import datetime
import numpy as np
from statsmodels.tsa.api import VAR
import statsmodels.api as sm

df = pd.read_csv('US_data.csv')

# converting str formatted dates to datetime and setting the index
j = []
for i in df['Date']:
    j.append(datetime.datetime.strptime(i, '%Y-%m-%d').date())
df['Date'] = j
df = df.set_index('Date')

# dataframe contains three columns (GDP, INV and CONS)

# log difference
df = pd.DataFrame(np.log(df)*100)
df = df.diff()

p = 4 # order
model = VAR(df[1:])
results = model.fit(p, method='ols')
sm.stats.diagnostic.acorr_breusch_godfrey(results)
```

Error message:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-6-11abf518baae> in <module>()
----> 1 sm.stats.diagnostic.acorr_breusch_godfrey(results)

/home/****/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/statsmodels/sandbox/stats/diagnostic.py in acorr_breusch_godfrey(results, nlags, store)
    501         nlags = int(nlags)
    502 
--> 503     x = np.concatenate((np.zeros(nlags), x))
    504 
    505     #xdiff = np.diff(x)

ValueError: all the input arrays must have same number of dimensions
```

A similar question was asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46302347/multivariate-breusch-godfrey-lagrange-multiplier-tests-in-python) over five months ago, but with no luck. Does anybody have an idea how to resolve this? Thank you very much in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Those diagnostic tests were designed for univariate models like OLS where we have a one-dimensional residual array. 
The only way to use it is most likely to use only a single equation of the VAR system or loop over each equation or variable.

VARResults in statsmodels master has a `test_whiteness_new` method which is a test for no autocorrelation of the multivariate residuals of a VAR.
It uses a Portmanteau test, which I think is the same as Ljung-Box.
The statespace models also use Ljung-Box for the related tests.

Comment: This is great. The `test_whiteness_new` worked, although it was not really suitable for my observations (works best in larger samples I believe). Looping over each variable did not yet succeed, but maybe next time it will. Thank you for taking the time answering my question.